# Using do loop and functions to make a menu. C

Tags: c

What seems to be the problem in my code?  I wish to make a program that makes allows the user to choose from a list of choices/menu. The user chooses one and a function runs. After the function executes the menu appears again until the user decides to quit.

My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

 int evaluate(int num);
 int binaryPrinter(int dec);
 int hexaPrinter(int dec);
 int militaryTime(int hh, int mm);

 int main(void)
 {
         int choice, x, y;

    do {
        printf("Type the number of your choice:\n1: Place value evaluation\n2: Convert a Decimal to Binary\n3: Convert a Decimal to Hexadecimal\n4: Convert Standard time to Military time\nEnter Number of Choice: ");
        scanf("%d, &choice");
        (void) getchar();

        switch (choice){
        case 1:
            printf("Enter number to be evaluated:");
            scanf("%d, &x");
            int evaluate(int x);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Enter a decimal number: ");
            scanf("%d, &x");
            int binaryPrinter(int x);
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Enter a decimal number: ");
            scanf("&d, &x");
            int hexaPrinter(int x);
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("Enter time in standard format: ");
            scanf("%d:%d, &x, &y");
            int militaryTime(int x, int y);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid choice. Please choose only among the choices.");

        }
    }while(choice != 5);
return 0;
}
```

This is what is displayed after inputing the number of choice: `Process returned -1073741819 <0xC0000005>`

### -EDIT-

I have recognized the mistake I have made. But the result's still the same.

here's my new code, but same error: `Process returned -1073741819 <0xC0000005>`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int evaluate(int num);
int binaryPrinter(int dec);
int hexaPrinter(int dec);
int militaryTime(int hh, int mm);

int main(void)
{
    int choice, x, y;

    do {
        printf("Type the number of your choice:\n1: Place value evaluation\n2: Convert a Decimal to Binary\n3: Convert a Decimal to Hexadecimal\n4: Convert Standard time to Military time\nEnter Number of Choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        (void) getchar();

        switch (choice){
        case 1:
            printf("Enter number to be evaluated:");
            scanf("%d", &x);
            evaluate(x);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Enter a decimal number: ");
            scanf("%d", &x);
            binaryPrinter(x);
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Enter a decimal number: ");
            scanf("%d", &x);
            hexaPrinter(x);
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("Enter time in standard format: ");
            scanf("%d:%d", &x, &y);
            militaryTime(x, y);
        default:
            printf("Invalid choice. Please choose only among the choices.");

        }
    }while(choice != 5);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d, &choice");` --> `scanf("%d", &choice);` . ditto.

Comment: This problem I see immediately is that you aren't actually calling any of your action functions.  All you're doing is declaring them.  The declarations are fine, but it's cleaner to put them at the top of the file rather than embedding them in your code.  But the main thing you need to to is *call* them.  Example:  `int evaluate(int x);` is a function declaration.  It doesn't cause the function to be called.  `evaluate(x);` is a function call.  It calls `evaluate`, passing it `x`.

Comment: The bad quote position that `BLUEPIXY` pointed out is probably what's causing your abnormal exit.  Since `&choice` isn't being passed as an argument, but is instead part of the format string, `scanf` is performing an invalid memory access.  Your compiler should have caught this with a warning.  Make sure you fix (or at least understand) *all* warnings before asking for help.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me of my mistakes. But the same error's happening. `Process returned -1073741819 <0xC0000005>`

Comment: Again you have missed `"` while reading the choice from the user in `scanf()`

Comment: I suppose I have not missed anything now. but still the same error `Process returned -1073741819 <0xC0000005>`

Comment: Make sure you recompile everything before trying it.  If that doesn't work, then you may have misunderstood something, or there may be additional bugs, but we'd have to see the code to understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your `scanf` statements are all wrong. It usually takes to parameters. A format string containing format specifiers to determine what kind of value and how many  values to read and a pointer to the variable were to store the read value (multiple pointers in case of multiple specifiers).

```
// What you got so far
scanf("%d, &choice"); // <-- format string and pointer to variables are combined

// How it should look like
scanf("%d", &choice); // format string "%d" containing 1 format specifier to read an int
                      // and a pointer to the variable choice to store the read value
```

Ok now to the next mistake. When declaring a function you need to write down the whole function header (`returnType functionName(ParameterType1 Parameter1, ParameterType2 Parameter2, ...)`) however when you want to call that funtion all it needs is its name and the parameters BUT whithout theire type.

So declaring a function like this `int evaluate(int num)` like you did at the very beginning of your code is fine but when calling it in your `switch` all it needs is the name (`evaluate`) and the values, or variables you want to pass to the function as parameters (`evaluate(x)`).

So now all together:

```
printf("Type the number of your choice:\n1: Place value evaluation\n2: Convert a Decimal to Binary\n3: Convert a Decimal to Hexadecimal\n4: Convert Standard time to Military time\nEnter Number of Choice: ");
scanf("%d", &choice); // scan an integer value and store it in choice

switch (choice)
{
    case 1:
        printf("Enter number to be evaluated:");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        evaluate(x);
        break;
    case 2:
        ...  
}
```

Comment: I have edited my code sir. I have edited my post. The same error is happening

Comment: @AngeloAdrian have a specific look at the call to `evaluate` in your edit and in my answer. See the difference? Yours: `evaluate(int x)` mine: `evaluate(x)`. Theire is no need to write the type of `x`. `evaluate` (well actually the compiler) nows that it will get a `int` as a parameter. Normaly your code wouldn't even compile like that.

Comment: Thank you sir. I have posted my new code with all the corrections you suggested. But same error persists sir `Process returned -1073741819 <0xC0000005>`

Comment: I have not made a body for my functions sir shouldn't that affect my code?

Comment: Well, yes. Your compiler should usually compain about that! What compiler are you using?

Comment: I am currently using Codeblocks sir.

Comment: Ok I'm not so firm with Codeblocks settings, but there should be a possibility to enable compiler warnings. goolgle will be your friend here. This strange return code is probably a compiler error, since the compiler notices a mistake in your code but doesn't tell you whats wrong. However adding the actual bodys to the functions should help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int evaluate(int num);
int binaryPrinter(int dec);
int hexaPrinter(int dec);
int militaryTime(int hh, int mm);

int main(void)
 {
     int choice, x, y;

  do
   {
    printf("Type the number of your choice:\n1: Place value evaluation\n2: Convert a Decimal to Binary\n3: Convert a Decimal to Hexadecimal\n4: Convert Standard time to Military time\nEnter Number of Choice: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    (void) getchar();

    switch (choice){
    case 1:
        printf("Enter number to be evaluated:");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        evaluate(x);
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("Enter a decimal number: ");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        binaryPrinter(x);
        break;
    case 3:
        printf("Enter a decimal number: ");
        scanf("&d", &x);
        hexaPrinter( x);
        break;
    case 4:
        printf("Enter time in standard format: ");
        scanf("%d:%d", &x, &y);
        militaryTime( x, y);
        break;
    default:
        printf("Invalid choice. Please choose only among the choices.");

    }
   }while(choice != 5);
  return 0; 
}
```

You have used wrong syntax of the `scanaf()`

**it's not like `scanf("%d,&choice");`**

**it is like `scanf("%d",&choice);`**

And also missed the syntax of function call

**it's not like `int evaluate(int x);` it is like `evaluate(x)`**